# TextView stroke changing the colour without redraw

Tags: android

I'm trying to set stroke property to a textView, but I can't change the colour of the stroke. I want to do that without redrawing the view.

Here is the snippet:

```
mTextView = (TextView) mOverlayLayout.findViewById(R.id.outputId);
mTextView.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
mTextView.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
mTextView.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(2);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[read this site u can change editext button textview but u have to knowledge about xml](http://angrytools.com/android/button/)

```
GradientDrawable gdDefault = new GradientDrawable();
            gdDefault.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            gdDefault.setCornerRadius(10);
            gdDefault.setStroke(10, 10);
            textview.setBackground(gdDefault);
```

*this is for programaticaly change stroke*

Comment: This code change the background to white, I don't need that